# Issue with .env file

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, typescript, instructions, testing

I'm just beginning to learn and I'm using the SolDev bootcamp however, I've found an issue where I get this error message,

```
PS C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair> npx esrun generate-keypair.ts
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana-developers\node-helpers\dist\index.js:23527
    throw new Error(
          ^
Error: Invalid secret key in environment variable 'SECRET_KEY'!
    at getKeypairFromEnvironment (C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana-developers\node-helpers\dist\index.js:23527:11)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypairgenerate-keypair.ts:9:1)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
Node.js v18.18.0
```

I believe I've already installed the right packages so I'm not sure why I keep getting the error.

Here is my generate-keypair.ts file,

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import { getKeypairFromEnvironment } from "@solana-developers/node-helpers";
const keypair = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");
console.log(
  `✅ Finished! We've loaded our secret key securely, using an env file!`
);
```

Comment: The error seems to be that your secret key is not formatted correctly. In what format do you have it in your .env file? Some libraries expect the format to be base58, some expect it to be in raw bytes (i.e. an array of numbers), some in hex. Which one are you using and have you tried the other two?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my .env file I have it as an array of numbers like this, SECRET_KEY=[52, 76, 43...].

Comment: Try converting it to a base58 string and hex string and if either of those will do the trick. I recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58 for converting to bs58 and trust you know how to convert to hex by yourself ;)

Comment: OK thanks I'll try that

Comment: Finally go it working, thanks again for the help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved their issue without posting the solution as a self-answer. If you think that the solution is of general interest to others, self-answer your original question and then accept your own answer!

Comment: Added my comments as an official answer & proposed a different question title to be more broadly applicable. Please accept the answer @Ghost .

Answer (score 2):

Different client side libraries expect different formats for secret keys. The three most common formats are:

- Raw bytes (usually in the form of a `Uint8Array` in Typescript/just an array of numbers in an .env file)
- Hexadecimal
- Base58

Trying these three does the trick for everything I've encountered, otherwise check the official documentation for the tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the secret key stored in your `.env` file is incorrectly formatted, giving this error.

If you look at the [docs for the `@solana-developers/node-helpers`](https://github.com/solana-developers/node-helpers/?tab=readme-ov-file#secret-key-format) package, it describes the correct way to format the key stored in in the `SECRET_KEY` environment variable.

Specifically, the `` is expecting a base58 encoded string of the secret key. You can create one for your keypair using this:

```
const secret_key_string = base58.encode(randomKeypair.secretKey);
```

Then store this `secret_key_string` value inside your `SECRET_KEY` environment variable